# docker-compose returning apache2-foreground not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two simple containers, `web` and `db`.  I built and can successfully `up` the containers via `docker-compose` on both Windows and Ubuntu.  However, when I attempt to `up` on Photon, I get the following error for my `web` container.

```
Handler for POST /v1.21/containers/.../start returned error: Container command 'apache2-foreground' not found or does not exist.
```

But when I build the image based on the Dockerfile, and `docker run web`, it launches and runs fine.  Any ideas about this error?

Answer (score 1):

- `apache2-foreground` is a command (script) that calls `apache2 -DFOREGROUND` (see httpd/php repos/containers). It's the command automatically run by php/httpd containers
- If you run into a problem running a command from `docker-compose` that will ordinarily run with `docker` then it could probably be a bug - [see this for instance](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1618)
- It could also be the case that you actually have bad paths in your docker-compose.yml volume mappings